# Include TAG with click listener

Tags: android, button, include, click, fragment

I have one Fragment with two include external layouts:

```
        <include
        android:id="@+id/buttonSelectDate"
        layout="@layout/content_dateinstall_datebutton"
        android:layout_width="141dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_marginStart="38dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="35.9dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/txtInsertPhoneNumber"/>

    <include
        android:id="@+id/buttonSelectPeriod"
        layout="@layout/content_dateinstall_periodbutton"
        android:layout_width="141dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_marginEnd="38dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="35.9dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/txtInsertPhoneNumber"/>
```

I want to set OnClick method because i gonna use that layout as button.

when i set onclicklistener of the View the app crashes in the run time. I have been trying to Bind onClick by ButterKnife with @BindView and @OnClick and with common way, creating object and seting the onClickListener.

Anyone know how can i do that?

This is my buttonLayout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
<data>
    <variable name="orderViewModel" type="com.oi.pap.viewmodels.OrderViewModel"/>
</data>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
    android:layout_width="141dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/custom_border_button">

    <TextView
        style="@style/TextAppearance.simplonRegular"
        android:id="@+id/txtSelectPeriod"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/all_period"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="11dp"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:textColor="@color/lipstick"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"/>

    <TextView
        style="@style/TextAppearance.simplonHeadline"
        android:id="@+id/txtSelectPeriodValue"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@={orderViewModel.periodInstallValue}"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="11dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/txtSelectPeriod"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Post the error log.

Answer (score 0):

from what i see you try to access from your main layout to the include layout and you are using MVVM method, the main problem when you try to access the inside include layout it cannot get what is the data have been declared, so you have to declared it as well in the main layout then pass it to the include layout as well for example:
in my LoginLayout.xml:

```
<data>
    <variable
        name="activityLogin"
        type="...LoginViewModel"/>
</data>
```

in here I got want to get data access from activity Login then in include:

```
<include
    ....
    bind:contentLogin="@{activityLogin}"
    ..../>
```

in content login:

```
<data>
        <variable
            name="contentLogin"
            type="...LoginViewModel"/>
    </data>
```

then, that's it you get the data from your click

Comment: I have just one ViewModel by activity. The fragments are using the same viewModel of her father.

Comment: but if you use include in your layout, i think you might need to put `bind` inside it to access your other layout, if you use directly to your layout I think it will not recognize the `<data>`, because you are not inflate `content_dateinstall_periodbutton` that's why you got error. your `content_dateinstall_periodbutton` is children inside `layout.fragment_dateinstall_home` so you need passing the value from parent to your child

Answer (score 0):

I found.

```
private FragmentDateinstallHomeBinding dataBinding;
dataBinding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater, R.layout.fragment_dateinstall_home, 
container, false);
View view = dataBinding.getRoot();
//here
dataBinding.buttonSelectDate.dateInstallButtonLayout.setOnClickListener(tst);
```